# How to connect nginx to my java module

Tags: java, web-services, rest, nginx

I am a really beginner on this topic, I need some helpful articles and your guidance.
I want to build `RESTFul` API web service. As a http server chosen `nginx`. But I don't know (couldnt find any article) anything about how I can redirect my query to my java module, which handles request and gives back in `JSON` to `nginx`. If my thoughts on type of back-end is not correct please help me to figure out on this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to build your Java service in its own app server -- Tomcat would be a good choice for this. From there, it's a simple matter of configuring `nginx` to act as a proxy to Tomcat. Your `nginx` configuration will look something like the following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80; #incoming port for nginx
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
    }

#...and other things, like basic settings, logging, mail, etc.
```

The important piece here is the setting for `proxy_pass`. That's telling `nginx` to accept requests on port 80 and redirect them to port 8080 (Tomcat's standard port).

Answer (score 3):

With [nginx-clojure](http://nginx-clojure.github.io) we can write content handler,rewrite handler, access handler and header filter in java, clojure or groovy. e.g.

in nginx.conf

```
   location /java {
      content_handler_type 'java';
      content_handler_name 'mytest.HelloService';
   }
```

HelloService.java

```
package mytest;

import java.util.Map;

import nginx.clojure.java.ArrayMap;
import nginx.clojure.java.NginxJavaRingHandler;
import static nginx.clojure.MiniConstants.*;

public  class HelloService implements NginxJavaRingHandler {

@Override
public Object[] invoke(Map<String, Object> request) {
    return new Object[] { 
            NGX_HTTP_OK, //http status 200
            ArrayMap.create(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain"), //headers map
            "Hello, Java & Nginx!"  //response body can be string, File or Array/Collection of string or File
                };
    }
}
```